# GeoServer web application

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2

I'm trying to create a web application using GeoServer.

When I try to see the file var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/geoserver/data/www/ol-demo.html, no map appears, just  the title "GeoServer OpenLayers Demo" the frame, the zoom in/out.

I have installed GeoServer 2.8.1.

When I make a selection of a layer, I can see them through GeoServer in OpenLayers, but when typing http://localcost:8080/geoserver/www/ol-demo.html or ..../mytest.html, I see the page (no error 404) but I cannot see any map.

Can you help me?

Comment: when I explore the developer tools I get 3 errors:  Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND    file:///geoserver/style.css                                          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED  http://api.maps.yahoo.com/ajaxymap?v=3.0&appid=euzuro-openlayers             Uncaught TypeError: OpenLayers.Layer.VirtualEarth is not a function   ol-demo.html:69

Comment: Have you checked if those files are actually missing? might be worth building a quick web map using qgis and qgis2web then see if your server will serve that, then add some layers from your geoserver and see if they display.

Comment: Are you typing the url into a browser or double clicking the file in Explorer?

Comment: @ iant , I type the url, it does not work,   Does someone know were I can find the exact directories the files should be stored? I think it is a problem in the paths, the maps I create can be visible through the openlayers in geoserver, but then through the http it is not visible..